# How do you Chrome and Javascript to detect a specific text value in a webpage and save it as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

(I have limited knowledge in js, much more so with Chrome's API)

Basically I'm trying to make an extension that gets the text from this HTML code from a webpage

```
<div class="statuslabel">
     <span class="server-status-label-left queue-time">ca. 21 min</span>
</div>
```

and store it as a variable for further use later.

I can't find anything online (yet), and don't know exactly how to search a page for that specific string of code.

Bigger Picture:
I am making an extension that checks that code and gets the time value. If the time value is = 1:00 then it activates a restart button.

Comment: you can use innerHTML on classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelector('.statuslabel').textContent if there is just the one element having that class type on the page (or at least it is the first one) Otherwise, you should choose another class of element (or id - that's gonna be much better)

```
const text = document.querySelector('.statuslabel').textContent
```